# How to initialise WPF navigation bar on application start

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationbar

I have a window with a `FrameContent` that I use to navigate between pages:

```
<Frame Name="FrameContent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,34,-0.8,0.4" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

It works great, but it only appears after I have already navigated to a page, where I would like to see it (even though back/forward will be greyed out) from the beginning.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FrameContent.Navigate(new HomeView());
}
```

I tried adding

```
ShowsNavigationUI="True"
```

Attribute to the `HomeView` page but it did nothing.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `NavigationUIVisibility="Visible"`, let me know if it works.

Comment: Adding `NavigationUIVisibility="Visible"` to the `Frame` solved it thanks